# Declaring a structure array that has structure arrays inside

Tags: c++, io, binary

So I have a two structs that I have put in one for the use of file io and I want to know how I declare the struct when reading them. So if I am reading them from a binary file and using the techniques from this site: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall01/binio.html, how do I need to go about declaring the structs inside the main one(as far as type name = new type[size])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
struct outerStruct
{
    // Outer structure data

    struct innerStruct
    {
        // Inner structure data
    } innerData[SOME_SIZE];

    // Other outer structure data
} outerData[SOME_OTHER_SIZE];
```

---

If you don't know the size of the "arrays" you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
struct outerStruct
{
    // Outer structure data

    struct innerStruct
    {
        // Inner structure data
    };

    std::vector<innerStruct> innerData;

    // Other outer structure data
};

std::vector<outerStruct> outerData;
```

However, then you can't read the `outerStruct` structure "as is" directly from the file.

Comment: You've saved me a lot of googling, cheers